# Abaqus elastic-perfectly plastic Euler-Bernoulli beam

Tags: abaqus, abaqus-odb

I want to model an elastic-perfectly plastic Euler-Bernoulli beam in Abaqus to check the spring back effect.  The material model is elastic perfectly plastic. I am applying concentrated moments at specified locations. what should be the process?